# In Indian census, were the children of a Thug recorded as "Yet to Be Thug"?

Tags: india, law, british-empire, colonization, census

I read (can't remember where at the moment) that in a population census (probably around 1911) the child of a [thug](https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2013/11/18/245953619/what-a-thugs-life-looked-like-in-nineteenth-century-india) used to be recorded as  "yet to be thug" in profession column in India. This is because of criminal tribe act, around 1900. I searched in Internet but could not find anything.

I might have misplaced the time, but I am quite sure that an academic in lecture mentioned what I wrote, now, a way should be examining the document of census of British Empire around that time but only document I can find is [piketty](http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/files/ideologie/data/CensusIndia/CensusIndia1871/CensusBritishIndia1871.pdf)

Is it true? How can I find a reference to cite?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: It seems unlikely, since the thug cult was [essentially extinct by 1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thuggee#British_suppression), and the first [census of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_of_India) wasn't carried out until 1881. The [Criminal Tribes Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_Tribes_Act) targeted a wide range of communities designated as "habitual criminals".

Comment: @sempaiscuba I might have misplaced the time, but I am quite sure that an academic in lecture mentioned what I wrote in the post couple some time ago, now, a way should be examining the document of census of British Empire around that time but only document I got is: http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/files/ideologie/data/CensusIndia/CensusIndia1871/CensusBritishIndia1871.pdf

Comment: @Michael _please_ don't include relevant information in comments; I've moved the information into the question.  You're more likely to get an answer if all the information you have is included in the question.

Comment: Hmm.  It seems it might be possible after all.  A [census of the North-west Province, carried out in 1965](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QQwJAAAAQAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) did record 2 individuals as "Thug", although I didn't see any mention of children with that label in the report (though that was relying on searching the OCR text).

Comment: The authorities did not know who were Thugs.  This was so vital that captured Thugs could escape the death penalty by cooperating with the authorities.  Blandly recording that a child was to be a thug would require knowing that -- and letting the parent escape arrest.